# How do i use the direction property for a bootstrap 4 carousel?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I see on the documentation page for bootstrap's carousel there is a property for direction under the events tab but i don't know the syntax to use it and can't find any examples, would appreciate any help on this.

From bootstrap's carousel documentation:

> Bootstrap’s carousel class exposes two events for hooking into carousel functionality. Both events have the following additional properties:
>
> direction: The direction in which the carousel is sliding (either "left" or "right").
> relatedTarget: The DOM element that is being slid into place as the active item.
> from: The index of the current item
> to: The index of the next item

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: No i've switched to using slick instead of bootstraps carousel, thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

The carousel will emit an event called `slide.bs.carousel` (This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition).

That event object has a property called `direction` (and its value is either "left" or "right").

```js
$(function() { $("#carouselExampleControls").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
    console.log(e.direction);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```